# Relative binding in style of control inside ListBoxItem template

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

**My problem** is with the following code, with binding the `IsAvailable` property of the `MyListBoxItem` class. My current solution:

```
<ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myTemplate}">
  <ListBox.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="myTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:MyListBoxItem}">
      <Label Foreground="Green" Content="{Binding Title}" Tag="{Binding IsAvailable}">
        <Label.Style>
          <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
            <Style.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
              </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
          </Style>
        </Label.Style>
      </Label>
    </DataTemplate>
    ... (more datatemplates)

  </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

**My question:** In my solution the value of `IsAvailable` "goes through" two bindings. The first one binds the value to the `Tag` property of the `Label` and then in the style triggers, a trigger checks its value and sets a property of the `Label`. When I used `Binding="{Binding IsAvailable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MyListBoxItem}}}"` it didn't work, because the `Style` can't see any ancestor of the `Label` (or something similar reason), it resulted binding errors (with code 4 or 40 maybe), for each item added to the `ListBox`.

So finally: can I make the solution more simple, or there is no another (better) one?

An important thing I've forgot to mention, *sorry*: I put the `DataTemplate` in the ListBox's resources because I have more templates (they are basically differ, so I can't style them with triggers), which I have to switch between sometimes...

Answer (score 0):

The `ItemTemplate` will take the type that the `ItemsSource` is bound to. Therefore you should be able to simply bind to `IsAvailable`, as the ListBox's item type is `MyListBoxItem`. Try this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="...">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Foreground="Green" Content="{Binding Title}" Tag="{Binding IsAvailable}">
                    <Label.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Label.Style>
                </Label>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

You'll need to set your `ItemsSource` property to a `Binding` to the `MyListBoxItem` collection.